# How to pass reference to pointer managed by std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

In this code `getDatabase` function is 3rd party and I can't change it. Inside `main` function I have used `shared_ptr`. So there is a requirement I have to pass a `Database*` to the `getDatabase` function by reference. How can I achieve this?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <memory>

 class Database
 {
 };

 void getDatabase(Database*& pDb)
 {
     pDb = createNewDatabase();
 }

 int main()
 {
     std::shared_ptr<Database> pDb=NULL;
     getDatabase(pDb.get()); // Here is the issue pDb.get() doesn't do what I need   
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why not first create a raw pointer, call the API, then construct the smart pointer on the raw pointer?

Comment: I know there can be multiple workarounds. But here I would like to know is there a direct way to  pass reference to pointer managed by std::shared_ptr. Hope you understand my point

Comment: If shared_ptr was allowed to provide a non-const reference (lvalue) to its embedded raw pointer, we would not call it a *smart* pointer

Comment: @ASH: plus 1 for point of view :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shared_ptr::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) returns the managed pointer by value, so you can't bind the return value to a non-`const` reference.

The way to get around this is to first use a raw pointer to create the database, and then transfer ownership to the `shared_ptr`. You can optionally wrap that code in your own overload of `getDatabase()` to keep your call site clean.

```
void getDatabase(Database*& pDb)
{
    pDb = createNewDatabase();
}

std::shared_ptr<Database> getDatabase()
{
    Database *db = nullptr;
    getDatabase(db);
    return std::shared_ptr<Database>{db};
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Database> pDb{getDatabase()};
}
```

Comment: + for the idea of overloading the function.

Comment: I agree for your workaround. But actually my question was is there a way to directly pass the reference to the pointer inside the smart pointer.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya There isn't, that's why I posted the workaround